# Full Screen width CSS Framework for faster designing

Tags: css, styles, width, css-frameworks

I've come up with several Fixed width CSS Frameworks such as 960px GS and grid Generators. The problem with them I found is their fixed width. although it works best with Normal screen but Can I get or someone assist me with a CSS Framework  that uses the entire width of the screen available. No of columns, gutter width etc are not much concerning factors.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: How about Twitter Bootstrap? You can create a custom build with just the responsive grid features you need. And you can customize the number of columns etc. before downloading.

Comment: Yes bro, I've also worked with the Twitter bootstrap, It is indeed a great CSS Framework which helps us in designing our pages very quickly. But you see, it Provides The fixed and the Fluid layouts but, they too are not spanning the whole screen. while the fixed layout has pixels in it and fluid layouts has %s in it. but NOT full screen width CSS Framework.

Comment: How is this not fullscreen? http://jsbin.com/ocoyes

Comment: It has a great ability of adapting screens with smaller width than the normal widths. But this is not the case when Your Screen gets large as compared to the normal widths. ]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Making % based grids are incredibly easy, I think unless you're going to be using all the features of something like Bootstrap, you're just giving yourself a lot of extra bloat. Making a responsive grid system takes no more than 10/20mins and you'll have exactly what you need, nothing more, nothing less.

[Here's a video](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/115-dont-overthink-it-grids/) about making a simple 2 column, % based grid.

[And here's a blog post](http://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/) going through pretty much the same thing if you prefer to read about it.

To make mobile specific CSS you'll need some media queries going on, [here's a post](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) about that.

Also, if you're going to use media queries, don't forget to put:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

in the `head` of your pages.

Comment: seems great. I shall watch the video and the article you linked here. Thanks.